# how I put sound in a silverlight animation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm trying to put a sound to play when the animation in my silverlight animation starts. I put the sound in the user control with blend, selected auto-play, and created a PlaySoundAction to play the sound on load. Nothing worked. Anyone knows what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Media Element? since you have not posted any code, here is a sample on how to include sound in silverlight

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourNameSpace.Sound1.wav");
media.SetSource(stream);
media.AutoPlay = false;

media.Stop();
media.Play();
```

Comment: I haven't post any code, because I haven't typed any code. I'm using Blend to make all this. I tried to add a MediaElement in Blend, but didn't work either. Could the problem be in my IE or something? There is a way to test this?